# PHP while loop Error

Tags: php

My query is right but its fetch zero result so why this while loop is print ones this statement No error please tell thanks in advance

```
while(mysql_fetch_array($query))
{   echo "<br>"."No Error"."<br>";  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query returns zero rows?

Comment: $query? is it a string or result of mysql_query?

Answer (score 1):

Please do a small debugging and put "echo mysql_num_rows($query);" just before that. It should tell you the exact number of records - and thus, the number of loops in while. mysql_fetch_array returns FALSE when no more records (or no records from the beginning).

Comment: Thanx friend this error is came because i used select query for count to default count was zero so mysql_fetch_array was working ones

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array() method takes result of running a query on database as parameter rather than query itself and returns a row as an array.

Correct code would be:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{   
   echo "<br>"."No Error"."<br>";  
}
```

For more details on mysql_fetch_array(), have a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php